# Bluemix SSML with PHP

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, ssml

I'm using PHP shell_exec to call the `Bluemix` Text to Speech API and my code is working well except when I call the text with `SSML` tags like my second code.

How could I use text and SSML in the same data query?

```
          $result = shell_exec("/usr/bin/curl -k -u 'XXX':'XXX' -X POST \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --header 'Accept: audio/wav' \
          --max-time 90000 \
          --output 'public/uploads/audios/padrao_bomdia.wav'  \
          --data '{\"text\":\"Hello! This is an test.\", \"voice\":\"pt-BR_IsabelaVoice\"}' \
          'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=pt-BR_IsabelaVoice'");

          $result = shell_exec("/usr/bin/curl -k -u 'XXX':'XXX' -X POST \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --header 'Accept: audio/wav' \
          --max-time 90000 \
          --output 'public/uploads/audios/padrao_bomdia.wav'  \
          --data '{\"text\":\"Hello!    <say-as interpret-as="letters">Hello</say-as> This is an test.\", \"voice\":\"pt-BR_IsabelaVoice\"}' \
          'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=pt-BR_IsabelaVoice'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does say-as interpret-as="letters" Hello   fragment need the escape slashes around 'letters'?

Comment: Yes! I tried to use without it but it didn't work. The return was null.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Only US-English Allison voice supports Expressive SSML. Isabela, the PT-BR voice, does not support SSML. That's why it's not working.

[Reference](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/text-to-speech/SSML-expressive.html#expressive):

> Currently, the service supports expressiveness only for the US English
>   Allison voice (en-US_AllisonVoice). Using the element with any other
>   voice returns an error.